# (PHP + JQueryTools) Javascript-filled input field returns null after POST

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, post

I'm running into a little problem on submitting an input text-field which should have value set by a javascript script.

this is my code for the form:

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylingIndex.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
<table border="0">
<form method="POST" action="begin.php?id=createfile">
<tr><td>Date 1</td>   
<td><input type="date" name="date1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Date 2</td>
<td><input type="date" name="date2"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>

<script>
$(":date").dateinput();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I check the $_POST value its empty. (the createfile.php is handling perfectly, that's not the problem), I think the problem is in the way i treat the Javascript but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

It looks like it's not assigning the value selected (the date) from the script, although it does appear client side, it just doesn't process it after submitting. Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Is jQuery included in the jQuery.tools.min.js file?

Comment: So, you are never seeing `date1` or `date2` being posted to `begin.php`?

Comment: :date refers to the date function in jquerytools called from line #4.Just to be clear: the javascript works, i can select a date perfectly fine, but when i submit it doesn't send the value i selected

Comment: What's with the crazy `</script>` tag after the `<html>` tag?

Comment: @putvande yes it does, its the complete query library + all tools

Comment: @DevishOne, i see.. removed that didnt help :(

Comment: After you click the **Go** button, what's the URL in the address bar?

Comment: @devishone, POST parameters aren't sent through url..

Comment: @Ray - crap, you're right. Can it be changed to `method="GET"` temporarily?

Comment: The date fields aren't submitted (by POST or GET)

Comment: Jon can you please elaborate, it should according to mentioned code?

Comment: @Ray I know it should, but testing in Chrome and looking at the request headers, the two date fields don't get submitted as part of the request, which is why they're not accessible in the `$_POST` array

Comment: @Jon, in safari it does submit the POST, it just has empty value. Strange! I don't get it :'( :)

Comment: Check out @liding's answer - you can't have a form within a table but wrapping all of the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely have some tidying up to do on your markup. Notice the closing of the input nodes. Could you just try this for me? Putting the script block up top and using the jQuery DOMready function?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/EuM4p/)

```
   <head>
   <script>
   $(function() {
       $(':date').dateinput();
   });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class="main">
            <table border="0">
                <form method="POST" action="begin.php?id=createfile">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date 1</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="date" name="date1" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date 2</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="date" name="date2" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!! (sorry for not able to vote up not 15 rep yet). My thank is big and will do when i have 15.

Answer (score 1):

simply drag the start and end tag of the form:

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylingIndex.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
    <form method="POST" action="begin.php?id=createfile">
<table border="0">
<tr><td>Date 1</td>   
<td><input type="date" name="date1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Date 2</td>
<td><input type="date" name="date2"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></td></tr>
</table>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
$(":date").dateinput();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: D'oh, can't believe I missed that!

Comment: It seems to be a small bug, but still unpleasant. =)